# Difference between ContainsKey and ContainsValue in Dictionary?

Tags: c#

how does containsKey differ from containsValue ?

```
public Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();


if(dictionary.ContainsValue("123"))
{

}
if(dictionary.ContainsKey("123"))
{

}
```

Comment: Well `ContainsKey` checks whether there's an entry with the specified *key* is in the dictionary, whereas `ContainsValue` checks whether there's an entry with the specified *value* in the dictionary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Dictionarys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e8ecdh9(v=vs.110).aspx) are mappings from a `key` to a `value`.

`ContainsKey()` checks if your dictionary contains a certain key, it is **very fast** - looking up keys (and finding the data associated with *that* key) is the *main strength* of dictionaries. You might need this, to avoid accessing a non-existent Key - read about [TryGetValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) in that case - it might be a better choice to avoid accessing non existing keys data.

`ContainsValue()` iterates over all values and checks if it is in the dictionary, it is a **slow and cumbersome** procedure because it needs to go to all values until the first one matches. Accessing values not by its key, but by iterating all is *not* what dictionaries are about.

Doing a `ContainsKey()` is fine, if you feel you need to do a `ContainsValue()` you are probably operating on the wrong kind of data structure.

Doku:

- [ContainsKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx) vs. [TryGetValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [ContainsValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a63811ah(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`ContainsKey` check given object (in this case `string` ) is exist in `Key`s. Dictionary use `hash`, so this operation is executed very fast ( O(1) complexity).

ContainsValue check given object (int this case `int` ) is exist in `Value`s or not.

```
public Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

dictionary.Add("123", 321);

if(dictionary.ContainsValue(321)) // return true
{

}
if(dictionary.ContainsKey("123")) //return true
{

}
```